# Augmented reality app : convert a drawing into a animated 3D model

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

lately i've been discovering AR and it's implementations so i decided to learn by coding a mobile application (for both ios and android). The Objective is to recognize 3 drawings (with phone camera) and show the 3D model with animations of the drawing.

I have never done mobile development and I have almost no idea about augmented reality, if you can help me with the technologies I can use to create this project or even tutorials I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ARCore can display your 2d image on a 3D plane. Place the ImageView inside the inflated layout using a ModelRenderable.

Comment: YES ! that's exactlt what i needed ! thank you mate !